# How can I get POSIX file descriptor in Java 11?

Tags: java, java-11

I have method, which using `sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaIOFileDescriptorAccess().get(FileDescriptor)` by **Java 8** for getting the real POSIX file descriptor. In **Java 9 (and upper)** **SharedSecrets** was migrated to `jdk.internal.misc`.

How can I get POSIX file descriptor in Java 11?

```
private int getFileDescriptor() throws IOException {
      final int fd = SharedSecrets.getJavaIOFileDescriptorAccess().get(getFD());
      if(fd < 1)
                throw new IOException("failed to get POSIX file descriptor!");

      return fd;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no supported way to do this. Hacks like you have in the question are way too fragile and can break at any time.

Comment: Did you ever resolve your problem?  I am trying to get PI4J to work on my Raspberry Pi which only has Java 11 and face the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, but no, i used AlexC's example. And I decided that it’s better to use python for raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only to be used in case of emergency (or until you find a different way since this is not supported) because it does things unintended by the API and is not supported.  Caveat emptor.

```
package sandbox;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class GetFileHandle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("somedata.txt")) {
            FileDescriptor fd = fis.getFD();

            Field field = fd.getClass().getDeclaredField("fd");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object fdId = field.get(fd);
            field.setAccessible(false);

            field = fd.getClass().getDeclaredField("handle");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object handle = field.get(fd);
            field.setAccessible(false);

            // One of these will be -1 (depends on OS)
            // Windows uses handle, non-windows uses fd
            System.out.println("fid.handle="+handle+"  fid.fd"+fdId);
        } catch (IOException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's help me. I'll find different way

Comment: I am finding that the line "field.setAccessible(true);" throws an InaccessibleObjectException with the exception message of "Unable to make field private int java.io.FileDescriptor.fd accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to module FileTest".  I am assuming that there is a way to access this field since it is visible in the Eclipse debugger.

Comment: @StevenF.LeBrun  Depends on JDK version, I wonder if the hole has been plugged in a newer version of the JDK since this is definitely a hack.